# Nesting Jquery tabs within multiple accordions

Tags: jquery, menu, tabs, accordion

http://jsfiddle.net/SamHats/gjFUT/

I'm trying to create a menu with JQuery using tabs within accordions. I need to have the tabs content showing outside of the accordion.

I'm currently stuck with only the first accordion showing tabs.

My thinking is I need to add tabs classes but I'm pretty new to JQuery.

```
$(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs().addClass("ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix");
    $("#tabs li").removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-left");
});
```

Comment: is not going to work, you are breaking tabs widget structure apart. Can style links in accordion to look like tabs, and create your own content rendering code from ths links

Comment: Yerrr didn't think Jquery was enjoying it at all, Thanks. going to change the accordions to separate pages instead. Will help load time I guess because of all the youtube videos.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want this :
I cut the div of menu and place it above the accordian

http://jsfiddle.net/gjFUT/2/

```
<body>
    <div id="tabs">
         <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Records</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Notes</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Diary</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        <div id="accordion" class="panel" style="clear:both">
                <h3>Darwin Tutorial</h3>


             <h4>User Guide</h4>

            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-4">Other 4</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-5">Other 5</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-6">Other 6</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
             <h3>Support</h3>

            <div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="rightpanel">
            <div id="tabs-1">
                    <h2>Records</h2>

                <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/cJLzekuukEE"
                frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-2">
                    <h2>Notes</h2>

                <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/cJLzekuukEE"
                frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-3">
                    <h2>Diary</h2>

                <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/rtfS2eFwdgw"
                frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-4">
                <h2>Other 4</h2>

            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/cJLzekuukEE"
            frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-5">
                <h2>Other 5</h2>

            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/cJLzekuukEE"
            frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-6">
                <h2>Other 6</h2>

            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/rtfS2eFwdgw"
            frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
```

correct me if i am taking your question wrong

Comment: Kinda need the tabs within the accordion.